# Manually Add Program to Open With in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-association, irfanview

I have a standalone version of IrfanView (x64) and want it to appear in the Open With menu for all image files. I do not want it to be the default program however. For some reason no matter what I do, it doesn't want to enter this list. It doesn't even appear in the 'more apps' menu after clicking Open With. Here are the things I tried (in no particular order):

- Opening the file with IrfanView
- Assigning IrfanView as the default application and then re-assigning the previous app
- Following the instructions here: [Add items to the "Open with" list in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/690106/add-items-to-the-open-with-list-in-windows-8) (the relevant registry key already exists!)
- Downloading Default Programs Editor (it doesn't seem to have this option, and I don't want to add an "Edit with IrfanView" shell option)
- Following the instructions here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/178066-open-add-program.html (the problem is that the site hosting the relevant app appears to be permanently down)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should retry [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/).

Don't click on "Context Menu" but rather on the option at the bottom - "Change'Open with' programs":

[image]

and then:

[image]

You may need to restart you computer for changes to appear.

Comment: It worked, no idea how I missed that link at the bottom.

Comment: Strange issue: all three programs I want actually show up in there, but Windows itself only shows 2 of them, no matter what I do...

Comment: @Nyerguds: That seems to be a bug of Windows 10. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1256482/62676) how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Another excellent tool is [OpenWithView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html), by Nir Sofer.

It is very much worth checking his other free tools.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a special case that required some alternate steps and wanted to share it in the likelihood that someone else runs into the same problem:

So I wanted to fix Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 *not* appearing in the initial Open With list for .sln files; only 2017 and 2010 (the later of which has never even been installed on this machine). Imagine my frustration when, according to Default Programs Editor, everything I want is already *in* the list.

And they in fact *were* already in .sln's `OpenWithProgids`, but it turns out MS invented a new `AllowSilentDefaultTakeOver` registry value for file classes in Windows 8 that [maybe does a few things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144152(v=vs.85).aspx), but among them seems to be preventing a program from showing up in the initial Open With list; because as soon as I removed the `AllowSilentDefaultTakeOver` value from the `VisualStudio.sln.12.0` and `VisualStudio.sln.14.0` keys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 finally showed up.

And just to be sure, I *added* `AllowSilentDefaultTakeOver` to the useless Visual Studio 2010 class, and **lo**, it disappeared from the Open With list!

So, if it seems like you've tried everything to get a program to appear in a file type's Open With list and it's just not working, look for an `AllowSilentDefaultTakeOver` value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[program's file type ProgID]`.  (Though, realistically, you'll probably only see this on older versions of Microsoft programs when you also have a newer version installed.)

Comment: I had the same issue of only 2010 and 2017 showing up and trying everything to get 2015 to show up. I removed the "AllowSilentDefaultTakeOver" from the "VisualStudio.sln.14.0" classes and finally the 2015 open shows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Reg, try to add these two

1st

- go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\i_view32.exe` and creat new key named `SupportedTypes`, inside the key add files types as `String Value`, eg: `.jpg` `.png`

2nd

- go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache` and make sure you have these two strings values, if not, add them.

  ```
    (your*Irfanview.exe*location)i_view32.exe.ApplicationCompany
    (your*Irfanview.exe*location)i_view32.exe.FriendlyAppName
  ```